# API for getting movie soundtrack list

Tags: api, movie

Is there any free API for getting the list of soundtracks from a given movie?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

IMDB seems to be the best place for soundtrack lists.

This might be what you want:
http://www.deanclatworthy.com/imdb/